# Dynamic values not setting in nested array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the values of my nested object by using the data from another object but for some reason it is never setting the value. If i put static text in there it works but just doesn't work if the data from my other object

```js
const projectFormTypes = [
    {
        "type": "Theatrical",
        "sections" : {
            "project": {
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "label": "Project Title",
                        "name": "title",
                        "required": true,
                        "type": "textbox",
                        "visible": true,
                        'value': ''
                    },
                ]
            },
            "participants": {
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "label": "First Name",
                        "name": "firstName",
                        "required": false,
                        "type": "textbox",
                        "visible": true,
                        "value": "first name 1"
                    },
                ]
            },
            "earnings": {
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "label": "Compensation Amount",
                        "name": "wages",
                        "prefix": "$",
                        "required": false,
                        "type": "textbox",
                        "visible": true,
                        "value": 100000
                    },
                ]
            }
        }
    },
]



const projectData = [{"fileDetailRecordId":3,"detailRecordId":"341697P3","signatoryName":"comp 2","signatoryId":"comp sag","contract":"Theatrical","sagId":"aftra 2","title":"Project 2","principalPhotoDate":"2019-12-13","madeFor":"Interactive Media","ppe":"2019-12-13","sessionDateTv":"2019-12-13","marketPaid":"In-Flight","commercialTitle":"Project 2","sessionDate":"2019-12-13","useType":"Clip Use","ssn":"987654","firstName":"test","middleName":"test","lastName":"test","loanOutNumber":"45687","loanOutName":"54854","performerType":"Background","performerCategory":"Dancer","paymentType":"Payroll","wages":"852963","subjectToPh":"852963","phContrib":"8529363","contribPercent":"10.0000","detailStatus":"DRAFT","earningsFileId":341697,"detailStatusId":{"parentRefId":32,"activeFlag":true,"refCode":"detail_processing","refValue":"Processing","comments":"detail is being processed","createdBy":"NS","createdAt":"2018-10-04T01:33:18.000+0000","updatedBy":"NS","updatedAt":"2019-06-19T17:45:39.000+0000","cmsProcessEfDetailLogList":[],"referenceId":33,"cmsEarningsFileList":[],"cmsEarningsFileList1":[]},"createdBy":"UI","updatedBy":"UI"},{"fileDetailRecordId":1,"detailRecordId":"341697P1","signatoryName":"comp name","signatoryId":"comp aftra","contract":"Theatrical","sagId":"aftra id","title":"Project 1","principalPhotoDate":"2019-12-13","madeFor":"Foreign TV","ppe":"2019-12-13","sessionDateTv":"2019-12-13","marketPaid":"Network","commercialTitle":"Project 1","sessionDate":"2019-12-13","useType":"Phono Conversation","ssn":"456","firstName":"first name 1","middleName":"middle name 1","lastName":"last name 1","loanOutNumber":"456","loanOutName":"456","performerType":"AFTRA Staff","performerCategory":"Actor","paymentType":"Deferred","wages":"500","subjectToPh":"500","phContrib":"500","contribPercent":"1000.0000","detailStatus":"DRAFT","earningsFileId":341697,"detailStatusId":{"parentRefId":32,"activeFlag":true,"refCode":"detail_processing","refValue":"Processing","comments":"detail is being processed","createdBy":"NS","createdAt":"2018-10-04T01:33:18.000+0000","updatedBy":"NS","updatedAt":"2019-06-19T17:45:39.000+0000","cmsProcessEfDetailLogList":[],"referenceId":33,"cmsEarningsFileList":[],"cmsEarningsFileList1":[]},"createdBy":"UI","updatedBy":"UI"},{"fileDetailRecordId":2,"detailRecordId":"341697P2","signatoryName":"comp name","signatoryId":"comp aftra","contract":"Theatrical","sagId":"aftra id","title":"Project 1","principalPhotoDate":"2019-12-13","madeFor":"Foreign TV","ppe":"2019-12-13","sessionDateTv":"2019-12-13","marketPaid":"Home Video","commercialTitle":"Project 1","sessionDate":"2019-12-13","useType":"Clip Use","ssn":"123","firstName":"last name 2","middleName":"last name 2","lastName":"last name 2","loanOutNumber":"456","loanOutName":"456","performerType":"AFTRA Staff","performerCategory":"Dance Coreographer","paymentType":"Deferred","wages":"800","subjectToPh":"800","phContrib":"800","contribPercent":"50.0000","detailStatus":"DRAFT","earningsFileId":341697,"detailStatusId":{"parentRefId":32,"activeFlag":true,"refCode":"detail_processing","refValue":"Processing","comments":"detail is being processed","createdBy":"NS","createdAt":"2018-10-04T01:33:18.000+0000","updatedBy":"NS","updatedAt":"2019-06-19T17:45:39.000+0000","cmsProcessEfDetailLogList":[],"referenceId":33,"cmsEarningsFileList":[],"cmsEarningsFileList1":[]},"createdBy":"UI","updatedBy":"UI"}]

const pp = Object.keys(projectFormTypes).forEach(function(r) {
  for(let key in projectFormTypes[r].sections){
    for(let o in projectFormTypes[r].sections[key].fields){
      projectFormTypes[r].sections[key].fields[o].value = projectData[0][o.name];
    }
  }

});

console.log('result', projectFormTypes);
```

Comment: `projectFormTypes` is an array, so `Object.keys()` just returns the array index. Why not just do `projectFormTypes.forEach()`?

Comment: `o` is an index in the `fields` array. What is `o.name` supposed to be?

Comment: `o.name` should be `projectFormTypes[r].sections[key].fields[o].name`

Comment: `forEach()` doesn't return anything, what's the purpose of the `pp` variable?

Comment: I was using pp as a test to try to retrieve the data I may do something with it later. I dont know what you mean by o.name should be etc... Basically if the name is the same it should go something like projectData.title should replace the value in projectFormType fields .title if the name matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
projectData[0][o.name]
```

should be

```
projectData[0][projectFormTypes[r].sections[key].fields[o].name]
```

`o` is the index in the `fields` array, and numbers don't have a `name` property. You want the name of the current element of the `for` loop.

But the code is simplified and less error prone if you use `forEach()` for all the nested loops.

```js
const projectFormTypes = [{
  "type": "Theatrical",
  "sections": {
    "project": {
      "fields": [{
        "label": "Project Title",
        "name": "title",
        "required": true,
        "type": "textbox",
        "visible": true,
        'value': ''
      }, ]
    },
    "participants": {
      "fields": [{
        "label": "First Name",
        "name": "firstName",
        "required": false,
        "type": "textbox",
        "visible": true,
        "value": "first name 1"
      }, ]
    },
    "earnings": {
      "fields": [{
        "label": "Compensation Amount",
        "name": "wages",
        "prefix": "$",
        "required": false,
        "type": "textbox",
        "visible": true,
        "value": 100000
      }, ]
    }
  }
}, ]

const projectData = [{"fileDetailRecordId":3,"detailRecordId":"341697P3","signatoryName":"comp 2","signatoryId":"comp sag","contract":"Theatrical","sagId":"aftra 2","title":"Project 2","principalPhotoDate":"2019-12-13","madeFor":"Interactive Media","ppe":"2019-12-13","sessionDateTv":"2019-12-13","marketPaid":"In-Flight","commercialTitle":"Project 2","sessionDate":"2019-12-13","useType":"Clip Use","ssn":"987654","firstName":"test","middleName":"test","lastName":"test","loanOutNumber":"45687","loanOutName":"54854","performerType":"Background","performerCategory":"Dancer","paymentType":"Payroll","wages":"852963","subjectToPh":"852963","phContrib":"8529363","contribPercent":"10.0000","detailStatus":"DRAFT","earningsFileId":341697,"detailStatusId":{"parentRefId":32,"activeFlag":true,"refCode":"detail_processing","refValue":"Processing","comments":"detail is being processed","createdBy":"NS","createdAt":"2018-10-04T01:33:18.000+0000","updatedBy":"NS","updatedAt":"2019-06-19T17:45:39.000+0000","cmsProcessEfDetailLogList":[],"referenceId":33,"cmsEarningsFileList":[],"cmsEarningsFileList1":[]},"createdBy":"UI","updatedBy":"UI"},{"fileDetailRecordId":1,"detailRecordId":"341697P1","signatoryName":"comp name","signatoryId":"comp aftra","contract":"Theatrical","sagId":"aftra id","title":"Project 1","principalPhotoDate":"2019-12-13","madeFor":"Foreign TV","ppe":"2019-12-13","sessionDateTv":"2019-12-13","marketPaid":"Network","commercialTitle":"Project 1","sessionDate":"2019-12-13","useType":"Phono Conversation","ssn":"456","firstName":"first name 1","middleName":"middle name 1","lastName":"last name 1","loanOutNumber":"456","loanOutName":"456","performerType":"AFTRA Staff","performerCategory":"Actor","paymentType":"Deferred","wages":"500","subjectToPh":"500","phContrib":"500","contribPercent":"1000.0000","detailStatus":"DRAFT","earningsFileId":341697,"detailStatusId":{"parentRefId":32,"activeFlag":true,"refCode":"detail_processing","refValue":"Processing","comments":"detail is being processed","createdBy":"NS","createdAt":"2018-10-04T01:33:18.000+0000","updatedBy":"NS","updatedAt":"2019-06-19T17:45:39.000+0000","cmsProcessEfDetailLogList":[],"referenceId":33,"cmsEarningsFileList":[],"cmsEarningsFileList1":[]},"createdBy":"UI","updatedBy":"UI"},{"fileDetailRecordId":2,"detailRecordId":"341697P2","signatoryName":"comp name","signatoryId":"comp aftra","contract":"Theatrical","sagId":"aftra id","title":"Project 1","principalPhotoDate":"2019-12-13","madeFor":"Foreign TV","ppe":"2019-12-13","sessionDateTv":"2019-12-13","marketPaid":"Home Video","commercialTitle":"Project 1","sessionDate":"2019-12-13","useType":"Clip Use","ssn":"123","firstName":"last name 2","middleName":"last name 2","lastName":"last name 2","loanOutNumber":"456","loanOutName":"456","performerType":"AFTRA Staff","performerCategory":"Dance Coreographer","paymentType":"Deferred","wages":"800","subjectToPh":"800","phContrib":"800","contribPercent":"50.0000","detailStatus":"DRAFT","earningsFileId":341697,"detailStatusId":{"parentRefId":32,"activeFlag":true,"refCode":"detail_processing","refValue":"Processing","comments":"detail is being processed","createdBy":"NS","createdAt":"2018-10-04T01:33:18.000+0000","updatedBy":"NS","updatedAt":"2019-06-19T17:45:39.000+0000","cmsProcessEfDetailLogList":[],"referenceId":33,"cmsEarningsFileList":[],"cmsEarningsFileList1":[]},"createdBy":"UI","updatedBy":"UI"}]

projectFormTypes.forEach(function(type) {
  Object.values(type.sections).forEach(function(section) {
    section.fields.forEach(function(field) {
      field.value = projectData[0][field.name];
    });
  });
});

console.log('result', projectFormTypes);
```